# Draw overlay on camera iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

Users need to be able to take photo of their ID. I need to add a blue frame to camera view as a guide. Guide should have same aspect ratio on all device sizes and fit a label with instructions. Can I accomplish this using UIImagePicker?

Here is some incomplete code. Thanks for any help.

```
UIImageView *overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height - 16, self.view.frame.size.width - 16);
[overlayImage setFrame:overlayRect];
[self.imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:overlayImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AVCaptureDevice`, `AVCaptureSession`, `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and `AVCapturePhotoOutput`.

Set `AVCaptureDeviceInput` as input of capture session, and photo output as output of capture session. Initialize `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` with `AVCaptureSession` and add to your `view.layer` thought `addSublayer`. You can use `UIViewController` from storyboard or programmatically instantiated controller, add picture of overlay or cornered `view.layer.borderWidth` or `UIBezierPath`. Set up controller as `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`, add delegate methods. Use `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` method. Enjoy.