# iPhone 10 fullscreen camera non-working Xcode // iPhone 10 vs iPhone 8

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

[iPhone 10 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFtHD.jpg)

[iPhone 8 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WZ5m.png)

As you can see on a iPhone 10 screen camera is not full screen, and I can not understand what to change in Xcode if I want set camera view in a full screen in any device.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @HichemRomdhane I only cloned this repo https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager

Answer (score 0):

Did you use AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto ?

Comment: No, I haven't use it

Comment: It's UIImagePickerController?

Comment: You can use AVFoundation as i describe https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181481/4733648